# Empty field collection in hook_node_presave with entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a node with a field type field_collection which has 2 items:

```
$node->field_field_collection['und'] = array(
  0 => array('value' => 1),
  1 => array('value' => 2),
);
```

on the save node drupal fire hook_node_presave:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_node_presave.
 */
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $wrapper_counter = 0;
  $node_counter = 0;
  foreach ($ewrapper->field_field_collection->getIterator() as $delta => $fc_wrapper) {
    $wrapper_counter++;
  }
  foreach ($node->field_field_collection['und'] as $key => $value) {
    $node_counter++;
  }
}
```

after runing code

```
$wrapper_counter = 0;
$node_counter = 2;
```

what am I doing wrong?
I want to walk the field collection using entity_metadata_wrapper.

Drupal: 7.34
Entity API: 7.x-1.5
Field collection: 7.x-1.0-beta8

Comment: `EntityListWrapper` is iterrable, why the need for `->getIterator()`?

Comment: how to use it ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If your question has changed, please click the "edit" link and update it that way

Comment: how do I bypass the "field collection" using your answer?
"EntityListWrapper is iterrable, why the need for ->getIterator()?"

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was a comment asking you to clarify your choice to use `getIterator()`

Comment: to calculate the amount of field collection item 
I hook_node_presave walk this way 
(using "foreach ($ewrapper->field_field_collection->getIterator() as $delta => $fc_wrapper)")
the field collection and in the loop calculates the sum.

at some point, after you upgrade modules field_collection or entity this approach stopped working..
perhaps it is something else, I want to know..

it should be noted that in other "places" (not hook_node_presave) this method works perfectly
in this case, it turns out that in the object $node the data in field collection is,
and when using wrapper access lost..

Comment: @Clive was just saying that you can use "foreach ($ewrapper->field_field_collection as $delta => $fc_wrapper)" instead.  You don't need ->getIterator().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this way as per this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477202#comment-6040026):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_node_presave.
 */
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node -> type == 'my_type') {
    $field_field_collection = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_field_collection');
    foreach ($field_field_collection as $key => $value) {
      $fc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $value['entity']);
      $fc_name = $fc_wrapper -> field_field_collection_name -> value();
      dsm($fc_name);
    }
  }
}
```

See: [Understanding Field Collection Values](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477202) and [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) pages.